# How to pass Searched location Name to TextField in MKMapView in Swift?

Tags: swift, location, uitextfield, mkmapview

I am Using MKMapView to search location. I am able to search location on map, but here **how to send  its `Cityname and Street and pincode`  to its regarding textfields `pincodeField , cityField, streetField`**.

this code for search location:

```
class RegistrationViewController1: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var pincodeField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var cityField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var streetField: UITextField!
let searchCont = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

 override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

 self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
 if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
 locationManager.delegate = self

 locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
 locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
 }

    @IBAction func searchLocationButton(_ sender: Any) {
let searchCont = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchCont.searchBar.delegate = self
searchCont.searchBar.backgroundColor = .blue
present(searchCont, animated:true, completion:nil)
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
//create the search request
let searchReq = MKLocalSearch.Request()
searchReq.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text
let activeSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: searchReq)
activeSearch.start { (response, error) in
    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    if response == nil{
        print("error")
    }
    else{

        let lat = response?.boundingRegion.center.latitude
        let long = response?.boundingRegion.center.longitude

        self.annotation.title = searchBar.text
        self.annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat!, long!)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.annotation)
        //zooming annotation
        let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat!, long!)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
}

}
```

in the above code how to send searched location name, street, pincode to its textfield.. so that which we can pass it to JSON Parameters.

i am able to drop annotation in searched palce.. but how to send its cityname to its cityField.. help me with code.

Answer (score 0):

you need reverse geo coder or you can use google map api to send coordinates and fetch address and then parse. here is a example geo coder

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [CLGeocoder new];

CLLocation *newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:21.1700
                                                    longitude:72.8300];

[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation
               completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

                   if (error) {
                       NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                       return; // Request failed, log error
                   }

                   // Check if any placemarks were found                                                                    
                   if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
                   {
                       CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];

                       // Dictionary containing address information
                       NSDictionary *addressDictionary =
                       placemark.addressDictionary;

                       // Extract address information
                       NSLog(@"%@ ", addressDictionary);
                       NSString *address = [addressDictionary
                                            objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
                       NSString *city = [addressDictionary
                                         objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
                       NSString *state = [addressDictionary
                                          objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
                       NSString *zip = [addressDictionary 
                                        objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];


                       NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@", address,city, state, zip);
                   }

               }];
```

UPDATE: your code is swift try that

suppose you have

```
var currentLocation : CLLocation!
```

use this func to get adress

```
    func getAdress(completion: @escaping (_ address: String?, _ error: Error?) -> ()){
            let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
            geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(self.currentLocation) { placemarks, error in

                if let e = error{
                    completion(nil, e)
                } else {
                    let placeArray = placemarks
                    var placemark: CLPlacemark!
                    placemark = placeArray?[0]
//                    guard let address = placemark.addressDictionary as? JSONDictionary else {
//                        return
//                    }
                    let street = placemark.thoroughfare != nil ? placemark.thoroughfare!  : ""
                    let city =  placemark.subAdministrativeArea != nil  ?  placemark.subAdministrativeArea! : ""
                    let state = placemark.administrativeArea != nil ? placemark.administrativeArea! : ""
                    let zip =  placemark.isoCountryCode != nil ? placemark.administrativeArea! : ""
                    let country = placemark.country != nil ? placemark.administrativeArea! : ""
//
                    let address = "\(street) \(city) \(state)  \(zip) \(country) "
                    completion(address, nil)
                }
            }
        }
```

the usage is

```
if self.currentLocation != nil {
            self.getAdress { (jsonDict, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    return
                } else {
                    //let classObj = LocationOrganizer(jsonDict: jsonDict!)
                    let classObj = LocationOrganizer(str: jsonDict!)

                    print(classObj)
                }
            }
        }
```

and LocationOrganizer class is:

```
class LocationOrganizer {
    var locationString : String!

    init(str: String) {
         self.locationString = str
     }


}
```

and in your situation just convert CLLocationCoordinate2D to CLLocation

```
let currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
```

then call the func

Comment: i am not using current location.. i want searched location name in its textfield

Comment: You have already got long and latitude. Change current location to your location

Comment: when you clicked the searchButton you get the coordinates, right? then call getAdress() func. you will get full adress. parse the string for street, zip or in  getAdress func use yourt texZipFiield.text  =  placemark.isoCountryCode != nil ? placemark.administrativeArea! : ""